# Looking for a fanfic where Harry Potter and his son are in hiding. Voldemort kills Harry's son in the end

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I think Harry had run away with his son. The child was maybe about 4-6 years old. Voldemort finds them both and Avada Kedavra's Harry's son in front of the other Death Eaters. Harry's magic reacts extremely in his grief and kills Voldemort.

I remember Harry's son being a fairly precocious child who insulted or refused Voldemort in some way before he was killed. I think either Draco or Snape were hiding Harry and his son, but I could be wrong about that. I don't remember anything else.

This fic might've been on AO3, but my many searches there haven't found it. I'd be very grateful if anyone knows the title or author.